# .Net TimeZoneInfo ID - Is it Windows Language Specific?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, registry, timezone

I'm using the .net TimeZoneInfo FindSystemTimeZoneById method which I understand queries the registry. Are the values for Time Zone ID strings stored in the registry  at "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zone" dependent on the language of the Windows installation of the machine?

The registry key contains a value called "Display Name" so it would make sense for this to be the language specific one, but I can't find out if this is the case (short of installing a different language version of Windows). Can anybody let me know?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have since come to understand that the answer to this question is:

The Time Zone ID's are the same for all Windows languages.
The data within these keys may be different for different language installations.
The set of ID's installed will differ for different language installations.

It is badly documented and I can't find a reference for this, but I have compared several different version of windows (japanese, chinese, french, german, english) and these were my findings.

Answer (score 3):

> "Note The following time zone registry
>   file is for use only on English builds
>   of Windows. Several of the values in
>   the registry keys have been localized.
>   Therefore, these steps will work only
>   on English builds of Windows. To
>   create a registry file for non-English
>   builds of Windows, go to the "How to
>   create a registry file for non-English
>   builds of Windows” section"

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/914387

Hope that helps mate

Comment: I'm not sure if that helps or not. It certainly looks as if they are saying that you need a different set of timezone information for non-english builds, the format is completely different, but the IDs still appear to be the same.